# getting error 403 Forbidden SenderId Mismatch for new registration tokens while trying to send a notification message to FCM

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push, google-cloud-console

On my web project was used old GCM messaging, I migrate it to new FCM

I'm changed code on server for sending requests to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{my-project-id}/messages:send`.

I'm changed fronted JavaScript code for `pushManager.subscribe`, I add `applicationServerKey`, goten from firebase Web Push certificates Public key, and remove `gcm_sender_id` from `manifest.webmanifest`
So, now new registration tokens is getting successfuly and saved on my server.

NOW When I send notification message to old registration tokens, goten when I used GCM and `gcm_sender_id`, it is successfuly sended without errors.
BUT if I send notification message to new registration tokens, I always get error with code **403 Forbidden** and text error SENDER ID MISMATCH

I understand that senderId is a project-id in **Google Cloud console** and it is must be the same project-id in **Firebase** project, and this is actualy equal, and connected to one account.

I was trying to configure new project in **Google Cloud console** and new project in **Firebase** but nothing help, I was getting the same error.

What I made no right?

Answer (score 2):

Solved!

the problem was in:

I used `pushManager.subscribe` but this was wrong!

For firebase subscription it is need to use `firebase-app.js`, `firebase-messaging.js` and `messaging.getToken()`